# Are Heisenberg groups modulo $p$ 2-closed?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Have anyone ever published that the Heisenberg groups modulo $p$ ($p$ prime) are 2-closed groups? If yes, where can I find it?

(A permutation group $G$ is 2-closed, if the full automorphism group of the binary relation defined by the set of 2-orbits (orbitals) is the original group $G$. )

Comment: Could you provide a definition of being $2$-closed?

Comment: Tobias> question updated.

Comment: But what does if mean for a group (rather than a permutation group) to be 2-closed? (This is sometimes used to mean having a normal Sylow 2-subgroup, but that's clearly not what you mean here.)

Comment: Derek, you are right, it is nonsense to consider this property for an abstract group. With the specific action (in my problem) I will try to find the answer myself.

Comment: What is the correct behavior in this case: Should I delete the question?

Comment: It might be more helpful to specify a permutation action. You are allowed to answer the question yourself

Comment: Re *What is the correct behavior in this case*: Some related discussions on meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/my-question-makes-no-sense-what-do-i-do and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12351/should-a-question-with-a-flaw-be-deleted